# Calling an action in a child route

Tags: ember.js

I have deep nested routes:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('user', function() {
    this.resource('authors', function() {
      this.resource('books', function() {
        this.resource('chapters', function() {
          this.resource('chapter', {path: '/:chapter_id'});
        });
      });
    });
  });
  this.resource('home');
  this.resource('blog');
});
```

I got the following error on route:

Route: `/user/authors/books/chapters`

Error: `Error while processing route: chapters.index Cannot read property 'get' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

The reason of this error is that the model of the route `Books` is null.

I would like to have this logic: If one of the models of the various routes is empty, then create a Ember-Data record and fetch this new record to the model in question.

**Questions:** I have a `createBook` action in the `Books` route. Is it possible to call this action from the parent `Authors` route so that when Ember run the `Books` route's model, the model find the newly created Books record? Is my approach wrong? Should I use another logic?

Thanks

Comment: No idea if this works but did you try something like : `this.controllerFor('books').send(createBook")` with a bit it's may be bubbling to the route action. Otherwise i usually handle my actions in controllers even if there are always discussions between the pro actions in route and the pro actions in controller :)

Comment: and Btw, did you considered dependency injection ? :)

Comment: I try to minimize dependency injections, but it is an alternative. Good suggestion for controllerFor. I decided to escalate the actions in my child route to a parent route. Code is a bit more messy but that way I could call the actions... Thanks

Comment: It's a good thing to limit them ;) thus my first proposition was to try without however idk if it works, otherwise another solution would be to delegate the creation action to the controller. This has the advantage of letting you call the action from child routes, You can also keep your current route action if you used the native bubbling scheme and or keep your action in the route and then calling your method inside the controller.

Comment: Agree. This is a good alternative. Thank you for you help. If you wish to add this alternative as a solution, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to escalate the `createBook` action that was in a child route to a parent route. Code is a bit more messy (the `createBook` action is not under the `Book` route) but that way I could call the action from the `Authors` route.

I will gladly welcome a more efficient solution.